# Reducing memory pressure with many small classes

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am struggling with memory problems in some legacy code.
The code performs various tasks with huge point clouds, all based around the following data structure:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

At any time, a couple millions of these points may hang around in memory in various lists. Many of these stay in memory long enough to go into generation 2 of the garbage collection. Since the program runs in 32bit mode, virtual address space is limited.

The programs using this legacy code sometimes crash with `OutOfMemoryExceptions`. Even if they do not crash, they consume far more memory than they should, and virtual address space is frequently fragmented to the point where no continuous chunk of memory larger than 50mb is available (e.g. `MemoryFailPoint(50)` fails). A couple of methods have explicit calls to `GC.Collect()`, and removing those increases the frequency of the crashes.

Now, I know of a two ways to solve this problem, both of which I cannot use:

- Use a `struct` instead of a `class` for the points. Do not store those structs within a `List`, instead use `arrays`, to avoid copying the points with each access. Structs have far less overhead per instance than classes, and do not bother the garbage collector as much.
  Unfortunately this would require huge breaking changes to the code; the existing methods all expect the point class to be mutable, and references to individual points are passed around everywhere. The copy-by-value semantics of structs will cause all sorts of problems.
- Switch the whole app to 64bit. This would not reduce the memory, but would increase the virtual address space to a point where at least the app would not crash anymore.
  Unfortunately there are a couple of legacy 32bit dlls that prevent this.

Is there any other way I could keep working with the existing Point class in 32bit, but reduce memory pressure and ease work for the garbage collector?

Can I somehow allocate and free all those points myself in unmanaged memory, while still passing references around in managed code?

Or is there another workaround I have missed?

Comment: I haven't myself dealt with such a problem, but maybe [weak references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247(v=vs.110).aspx) could help here.

Comment: "At any time, a couple millions of these points may hang around in memory" - Are all of them neccesary at that point of time and are used? A solution would be not to have everything loaded in the memory all the time, but load/unload chunks of data based on current operation. Clearly that will introduce some overhead causing performance to degrade.

Comment: You can also create a "pool" of points and reuse the same instances over and over again. Of course that depends on how bad current situation is. If points are passed here and there and there is no point (in time) where you know given bunch of points is no longer used - that won't work. But you said you want to "allocate and free" those points yourself, and "pool" of points kind of does that (not exactly, but idea is the same).

Comment: Struct would be less memory but probably not help as not the whole object is in the List - not just a reference.  Do you really need double?

Comment: I did some tests with float instead of double: I was able to save 33% ( the original point class is 24 byte + 12 byte overhead, with floats it is 12 byte + 12 byte overhead.) With a struct I could save another 12 bytes for the class overhead.

Comment: Regarding the pool idea: I was not able to get any improvements, keeping track of which objects are no longer required was too complicated. I think a pool would be better suited if I had a few very large objects, instead of very many small objects.

Comment: What are the "various lists"? If you could introduce a `PointSet` where a bunch of points live and die together, you can simply implement points as indexes into lists, which eliminates fragmentation. You could still encapsulate those indexes as `Point` structs and keep the "fields" mutable through the magic of properties, which should keep most client code untouched, except code that deals with moving/copying points from one container to another. For hard cases where you can't easily track ownership you could maintain the original class, as long as the garbage collector was otherwise relieved.

Comment: The "pool idea" is a _very_ bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you already achieved significant improvement from 36 bytes down to 24 bytes by going from double to float:

> I did some tests with float instead of double: I was able to save 33%
>   ( the original point class is 24 byte + 12 byte overhead, with floats
>   it is 12 byte + 12 byte overhead.) With a struct I could save another
>   12 bytes for the class overhead. – HugoRune Sep 20 '16 at 16:19

You can get an additional 8 byte improvement by encapsulating a struct in your objects, and this achieves 16 bytes per Point (12 bytes for the floats with 4 bytes overhead), and saves an additional 22% for a total of 55%:

```
public struct PointFloat
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;
}

public class Point
{
    private PointFloat dbls;

    public float X
    {
        get { return dbls.X; }
        set { dbls.X = value; }
    }
    public float Y
    {
        get { return dbls.Y; }
        set { dbls.Y = value; }
    }
    public float Z
    {
        get { return dbls.Z; }
        set { dbls.Z = value; }
    }
}
```